# SQL increment a value based on different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1 looks like this:

```
Name             Date         Hours    HoursType   

Doe, John        8/7/18       22        A
Doe, John        8/7/18       10        B
Doe, John        8/7/18       5         C
Doe, Jane        8/7/18       15        A
Doe, Jane        8/7/18       40        B
```

I'd like a Select that adds an incrementing integer as an additional column
ideally it will produce results that looks like this:

```
Doe, John        8/7/18       22        A     1
Doe, John        8/7/18       10        B     2
Doe, John        8/7/18       5         C     3
Doe, Jane        8/7/18       15        A     1
Doe, Jane        8/7/18       40        B     2
```

The 5th column should start at 1 and increment by 1 for each line of Doe, John.
It should start back over at 1 for the next name.

Thanks

Comment: Is this SQL Server? If so, have you looked into using ROW_NUMBER? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER. It was made for this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Not sure how you order the rows since in your sample there is no way to ensure the order but pick something that makes sense with your real data.

```
select *
    , YourNewColumn = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Name order by HoursType)
from YourTable
```

Comment: Only thing is they want the new column to "reset" so probably need `rank`

Comment: @scsimon - According to the sample output this should be fine. It will restart with each new name. But maybe that isn't what they want.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables are unordered, and there is not an obvious ordering to the values.  The answer to your question is `row_number()`, but with some ordering column or expression.  For example:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by name order by (select null)) as hourstype
from t;
```

Note that the rows will be enumerated, but in an arbitrary order.  If there is a column for ordering, use that instead of `(select null)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE( [Name] VARCHAR(50), [Date] DATETIME, [Hours] INT, [HoursType] VARCHAR(1) );

INSERT INTO @data ( [Name], [Date], [Hours], [HoursType] ) VALUES
( 'Doe, John', '8/7/18', 22, 'A' )
, ( 'Doe, John', '8/7/18', 10, 'B' )
, ( 'Doe, John', '8/7/18', 5, 'C' )
, ( 'Doe, Jane', '8/7/18', 15, 'A' )
, ( 'Doe, Jane', '8/7/18', 40, 'B' );

SELECT
    [Name]
    , [Date]
    , [Hours]
    , [HoursType]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Name], [Date], [HoursType] ) AS RowNo
FROM @data
ORDER BY
    [Name], [Date], [HoursType];
```

Returns

```
+-----------+-------------------------+-------+-----------+-------+
|   Name    |          Date           | Hours | HoursType | RowNo |
+-----------+-------------------------+-------+-----------+-------+
| Doe, Jane | 2018-08-07 00:00:00.000 |    15 | A         |     1 |
| Doe, Jane | 2018-08-07 00:00:00.000 |    40 | B         |     2 |
| Doe, John | 2018-08-07 00:00:00.000 |    22 | A         |     1 |
| Doe, John | 2018-08-07 00:00:00.000 |    10 | B         |     2 |
| Doe, John | 2018-08-07 00:00:00.000 |     5 | C         |     3 |
+-----------+-------------------------+-------+-----------+-------+
```